# Fetching single activity from getstream.io

Tags: php, getstream-io

I'm trying to fetch a single activity from getstream.io on the server following a realtime notification and enrich it.

As you can see below, it returns null until full page is fetched.

```
// Websockets fired. There is a new activity $id. Fetch and enrich:

// Get activity that begins with the new $id
$options = ['id_gte' => $id];

// PROBLEM: First call to get single item returns NULL
$feed->getActivities(0, 1, $options); 

// Second call without conditions returns everything fine
$feed->getActivities(0, 15); 

// The desired activity is now present in response
$feed->getActivities(0, 1, $options);
```

Is there a better way to handle this or a specific time delay before id based filters are available on new messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for pointing this out. We can certainly improve our documentation to be more clear about how we handle this scenario.

When you use filters to fetch a feed, or non-zero `offset` values, Stream does not return new items on the feed.

When you call `$feed->getActivities(0, 15);` that's when we would send the value as part of the feed data to later also be available with filters.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Is there an alternative way to fetch that message or is fetching all of them the only way?

Comment: Since it's an activity you're sending to us at Stream, you already have everything you'd get back from us other than the Stream activity_id (which gets returned when calling the "add activity" API endpoint)